# Widgets on android fragment are not update and are not responding to clicks

Tags: android, widget, android-fragments

I have an Activity with Fragments.
On one of the Frgaments I added widgets.
I can see the widget as a "picture" but the widget is not updating itself. Also if the widget were capable to answer to clicks (on regular activity).. while is located on the Fragment is not.
Any idea ?

Comment: without seeing your code, very few people can answer your question.